# Operator overloading function not working when using the operator on return value of a function

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a simple Node class that creates Nodes and can access the strings inside these Nodes. I have two operator overloading functions in the class in order to be able to compare the Nodes ( > overloader) and print their data ( << overloader). There is also templated copy of the built in max() function. Both of my operator overloaders work as they should, except when I try to print the return value of the max() function with two Nodes as parameters. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T maximum(const T& a, const T& b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

class Node{
public:
    Node(const string& s = "Default"):
        data(s){

    }

    string get_data() const {
        return this->data;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os,  Node& a){
        return os << a.get_data();
    }

    friend bool operator > (const Node& a, const Node& b){
        if(a.get_data() > b.get_data()){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

private:
    string data;
    Node* next;
};

int main() {

    double d1 = 0.1, d2 = 0.2;
    cout << maximum(d1, d2) << endl;

    string s1 = "woody", s2 = "buzz";
    cout << maximum(s1, s2) << endl;

    Node a("buzz"), b("woody");
    cout << maximum(a, b) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem lies in the last line of the main() function. My compiler throws an error message saying something similar to `cannot bind ostream<char> value to ostream<char>&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `const` to second argument of `operator<<`:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Node& a){
                                          ^^^^^
```